# Dynamic object doesn't contain a definition for a property from a reference

Tags: c#, object, dynamic

The error I got :

> "object" doesn't contain a definition for "test"

[image]

I also tried `game.test()` but I keep getting this error

This solution is divided in two distinct projects :

- The first one is a .dll
- The second one is a console

the goal is to call the get method from the 'iw4mp' class dynamicaly. So I would be able to call any from the class while it will be loaded.
the COD class should look useless but in the futur it will look if the process is running on the computer but for my test I use a string (but it actually work same way as if it was looking for a process).

Code from the DLL

**COD**

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using CODOffsets.Interface;
using CODOffsets.Offsets;

namespace CODOffsets
{
    public class COD
    {
        static string[] games = { "iw4mp", "iw5mp", "bo1" };
        static Type CallofDuty;

        public static bool checkGame()
        {

            foreach (string game in games)
            {
                if (ProcessHandle(game))
                {
                    CallofDuty = Type.GetType("CODOffsets.Offsets" + "." + game);
                    return true;
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
        public static object Game()
        {
            return Activator.CreateInstance(CallofDuty) as ICODClass;
        }

        public static bool ProcessHandle(string game)
        {
            if (game == "iw4mp")
                return true;
            else
                return false;
        }

    }
}
```

**Interface**

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace CODOffsets.Interface
{
    interface ICODClass
    {
        string test { get; }
    }
}
```

**Offset**

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using CODOffsets.Interface;

namespace CODOffsets.Offsets
{
    class iw4mp : ICODClass
    {
        public string test { get { return "this is mw2"; } }
    }
}
```

Code from the Console project

**Main**

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Dynamic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using CODOffsets;

namespace TestGenericClass
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            if (COD.checkGame())
            {

                dynamic game = COD.Game();
                Console.WriteLine(game.test);
                Console.ReadKey();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is the definition of `CallOfDuty` class?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should basically work as the way you did. But, if not so, here are some alternatives.

you can use reflections in c# to get all the properties of the dynamic object.

```
var nameOfProperty = "test";
var propertyInfo = game.GetType().GetProperty(nameOfProperty);
var value = propertyInfo.GetValue(game, null);
```

Moreover, you can simply use this way to get the value if you know the property name

```
string value = game["test"];
```

Comment: good work around, I had the same issue. But i just figured out that it was because (just like they did) my other class was non-public, so i couldn't access the fields even dynamically (but your reflection trick works!).

Answer (score 0):

I think the real issue was that:

```
class iw4mp : ICODClass
```

was not a public class.

so even if you make it (dynamic), there isn't a property named "test" that you could access since you can't really access that type.

you can access non-public fields using reflection though.